# What's wrong with my Zend Framework route?

Tags: zend-framework

I have a problem with ZF, my code looks OK, but I can't take the parameter ID, it return true, and i'm accesing the url right http://site.com/admin/news/newsedit/1

So my code looks like this:

**Route**

```
$ad = self::$frontController->getRouter();      
$ad->addRoute('newsedit',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        'news/newsedit/:id',
         array(
            'module' => 'admin',
            'controller' => 'news',
            'action' => 'newsedit'
         )
    )
);
```

**Action**

```
public function newseditAction()
{
    /*
        Disable Layout
    */
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    /*
        @return : boolen OR string
    */
    $_id = ($this->_getParam('id') !== NULL) ? (int)$this->_getParam('id') : false;

    if ($_id) {
        /*
            @return : array
        */
        $_get = $this->news->select()->where('id = ?', $_id);
        if (count($_get) > 0) {
            $this->view->data = $_get;
        }
    }
    Zend_Debug::dump($this->_getParam('id'));
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Uffo: Where in your code are you adding the Route?

Comment: in the bootstrap, i have more routes and they work ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

First check if the routes are set in your controller. Use 
`print_r($this->getFrontController()->getRouter()->getRoutes());` 
to confirm.

If not, you are setting the router in the wrong instance.

Use:

```
$ad = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
```

instead.

on a sidenote:

```
 $_get = $this->news->select()->where('id = ?', $_id);
```

this doesnt return any rows. this is a Zend_Db_Table_Select object not an Zend_Db_Rowset Object.

You would need to do:

```
$select = $this->news->select()->where('id = ?', $_id);
$_get = $this->news->fetchAll($select);
```

or even easier:

```
$_get = $this->news->find($_id)
```

greetings

Comment: Hmm, your solution doesn't work for me :(.Could be this a problem:

  /*
   News pagination ADMINE SIDE 
      */
  $ad->addRoute(
   'admin_news',
   new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('news/:page', array('module' => 'admin','controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'index'))
  );
  
  /*
   News edit
  */
  $ad->addRoute(
   'newsedit',
   new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('news/newsedit/:id', array('module' => 'admin','controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'newsedit'))
  );

Comment: hmm you can't see the code right like this, try here http://pastebin.com/m71b2ce6b

Comment: what i dont understand is, why you do this in the first place, only to save you /id/ ?
eg. your url: http://site.com/admin/news/newsedit/1 Normal URL: http://site.com/admin/news/newsedit/id/1

try to switch the position of the routes you postet. i guess if you define news/:page this would be true for news/newsedit to. (newsedit would be page)